# Delete/Disable access to logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an mvc application where I want to delete AspNetUser. I am using `await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);` this appears to work while the user is logged out, however if hes logged in the deletion fails. I tried to use `await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id,"User");` which successfully removes the user from a role but this doesn't seem to affect the [Authorize] attribute until user logs in again. Is there any way I can completely delete a user who is currently logged in?

**edit:**
made some changes and now the deletion goes through successfully however my main issue is still unresolved and deleted user while still logged in can function just like any other user.

Simple way to put It I want to delete an logged in user so when he hits refresh or opens a new page he will loose his ability to modify or access things he shouldn't access anymore.

```
// GET: UserAcc/Delete/5
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    return View(db.UserAccs.First(x => x.Id == id));
}

// POST: UserAcc/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id, UserAcc userAccount)
{
    try
    {
        var userAccLocal = db.UserAccs.First(x => x.Id == id);
        var lessons = db.Lessons.Where(x => x.userAccLocal.Id);
        foreach (var lesson in lessons){ db.Entry(lesson).State =EntityState.Deleted;}
        var user = UserManager.FindById(userAccLocal.ApplicationUserId);
        //TODO 
        db.Entry(userAccLocal).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        db.SaveChanges();
        //IdentityResult roleResult = await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id,"User");
        IdentityResult DeleteResult = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here..

Comment: What error is showing when you are trying to delete

Comment: I have made some changes and the deletion seems to go through successfully now. However the logged in user isnt affected at all even when opening other pages/refreshing. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply *log out* the user from all sessions before deleting the account.

Comment: I do not have sufficient reputation to comment on the main post.